# C print out unexpected result of the same variable with different calculation

Tags: c, printf

I am new to C language, and I meet the problem with the printf.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define add1(x) ((x) = ((x)+1))


int main()
{
    int x, y, temp;
    x = 5;
    
    printf("Add 1 to %d is equal to: %d", x, add1(x));
    
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling and running this code, it shows the result:

```
Add 1 to 6 is equal to 6
```

What I expect is:
"Add 1 to 5 is equal to 6"

That is, what I expect is that the behavior of it will show the format specifier by order: "Add 1 to x" (x = 5), and then "is equal to: add1(x)" (x = x+1 --> x=6)
However, it seems that the compiler will compile add(x) simultaneously and directly make x = 6 while running to the line "printf("Add 1 to %d is equal to: %d", x, add1(x));"

Can someone help explain this problem with more detail? Thanks~

Comment: Undefined behaviour — anything is a valid result.

Comment: This code in this question used marginally different syntax from the pre-increment and post-increment notations, but the net result is the same — undefined behaviour because there is no sequence point between the different argument expressions being evaluated and there is no defined order in which function arguments are evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for providing the information about "Undefined behavior". I have looked for some articles introduce this topic, and those help me realize this issue more.

Comment: The `add1` macro is a bad idea.  Just write `x++` like the rest of the world.  Hiding it in a macro, and even worse, writing that macro to unexpectedly evaluate its argument more than once, is a bad idea.